# Regular expression: "between" : and a space

Tags: regex

I know there are a load of similar "combine 2 regular expressions" posts on here, but I've tried the solutions and keep getting errors.

I've got the regular expressions to parse a description such as:

```
Org Biomol Chem. 2011 May 7;9(9):3549-59. doi: 10.1039/c1ob05128h. Epub 2011 Mar 28.
```

to extract the DOI (Digital Object Identifier):

1. `([^:]+$)` -->  10.1039/c1ob05128h. Epub 2011 Mar 28.
2. `([^\s]+)` -->  10.1039/c1ob05128h.

But am pretty clueless as to how to combine these. If it's difficult, then it's not necessary, but would simplify my calculations.

I also can't figure out how to get rid of that last "." which is not part of the DOI string (for the record there may be more than 2 full stops in a DOI so the regex can't simply be "after the 2nd full stop").

Some other examples as requested:

```
Chem Soc Rev. 2008 Nov;37(11):2413-21. doi: 10.1039/b719548f. Epub 2008 Sep 16.
Small. 2010 Dec 20;6(24):2796-820. doi: 10.1002/smll.201001881. Review.
Org Lett. 2010 Oct 1;12(19):4248-51. doi: 10.1021/ol101920b.
Chemistry. 2010 Dec 27;16(48):14285-9. doi: 10.1002/chem.201002111. No abstract available.
```

All the attempts I've made so far give a result much the same as this:

[image]

Some of the exceptions to Dukeling's suggestion of "doi: ([^\s]+).? ([^:]+).?", for reasons unknown, were:

- Chem Commun (Camb). 2012 Dec 25;48(99):12094-6. doi: 10.1039/c2cc35588d.
- Org Biomol Chem. 2013 Jan 7;11(1):27-30. doi: 10.1039/c2ob26587g.
- Chem Commun (Camb). 2013 Jan 25;49(7):671-3. doi: 10.1039/c2cc37953h.
- Org Lett. 2010 Oct 1;12(19):4248-51. doi: 10.1021/ol101920b.Chemistry. 2010 Jul 26;16(28):8537-44. doi: 10.1002/chem.201000773.
- Chem Commun (Camb). 2012 Dec 25;48(99):12094-6. doi: 10.1039/c2cc35588d.
- Org Biomol Chem. 2013 Jan 7;11(1):27-30. doi: 10.1039/c2ob26587g.
- Chem Commun (Camb). 2013 Jan 25;49(7):671-3. doi: 10.1039/c2cc37953h.
- Org Lett. 2010 Oct 1;12(19):4248-51. doi: 10.1021/ol101920b.
- Chemistry. 2010 Jul 26;16(28):8537-44. doi: 10.1002/chem.201000773.

Comment: What do you need exactly, from what I can see the second regex matches a substring of the string matched by the first regex ? and what language or tool are you using ?

Comment: @Sniffer I'm looking for the DOI, in the example that'd be "10.1039/c1ob05128h" and I'm using Google Spreadsheets regexextract formula

Comment: The second item is part of the first, so combining them doesn't make much sense to me? You'll want to be more clear on what exactly you want as a result and what different inputs there might be, for example, show an example with "more than 2 full stops".... also, does "Epub" always follow the doi?

Comment: @ smerny Right, will edit the description

Comment: You are still not pretty clear about it, what is the exact output you are expecting from every example you have given ?

Comment: For the string `doi: 10.1039/b719548f. Epub 2008 Sep 16.`, Do you only want `10.1039/b719548f`?

Comment: Yes, it varies in length and the number of delimiters as shown in some of the examples, there are ones like "10.1016/j.bmc.2011.12.060", but I think I've got it thanks to Dukeling now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the `.` gone, this seems to work:

```
"doi: ([^\s]+)\."
```

So we're just putting the `.` outside the brackets, so it doesn't get grouped with the string.

If you want to extract `10.1039/c1ob05128h` and `Epub 2011 Mar 28` in 2 separate strings, you can do this with [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You can make the regex something like:

```
"doi: ([^\s]+)\.(?: ([^:]+)\.)?"
```

Given that the second part appears to be optional, we need to surround it with brackets which we mark as optional with `?` (and the `?:` makes it a non-capturing group, so you don't get that in your second cell rather than what you want).

And Google seems to automatically fill `=CONTINUE(..., 1, 2)` into the next cell, which gives you the two groups next to one another.

**The pursuit to make the `.`'s optional**

At first I tried just saying `\.?`, but obviously the `[^\s]+` will then consume the `.` (which is not desired).

So you need to include something inside the brackets to prevent this. Specifically, you need to check the last character and make sure it's not a `.`.

This led me to:

```
"doi: ([^\s]*[^.\s])\.?(?: ([^:]*[^.:])\.?)?"
```

This allows for optional `.`'s, but if there are more than 1 `.` at the end, it won't work. Assuming we want none of these in our output, it's easily fixed by changing the `\.?` to `\.*`.

```
"doi: ([^\s]*[^.\s])\.*(?: ([^:]*[^.:])\.*)?"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I don't know why this regexextract seems so incompatible with regular expressions that seem to be in use with Perl etc.? I've tried a few and found a lot of #N/A errors, can't see why though

Comment: Sorry, sure. Also did you add in a "?" at the end of your codes? That stops it working for me

Comment: @lmmx Sorry, the optional `.` seemed to have broken it. Just made it non-optional and now it looks fine (assuming the `.` is always there).

Comment: This was working, then I added a new column and it overwrote some of the empty cells with =CONTINUE for the text after the full stop meant to be a delimiter here. No idea what's going on really so going to go back to the sequential ([^:]+$) then ([^\s]+)\. which at least I understand - probably poor implementation on Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(cell;"doi: ([.\d]+\/[\w\.]+)\.(?: |$)")
```

--> it extracts 10.1039/c1ob05128h
No need to combine regular expressions, it can be done at once.

I tried it on all of your examples and it works.

Comment: Wouldn't work for me, I'm not sure if Google Spreadsheets isn't compatible with the entirety of regex... Thank you though

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer and tested it on Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may do the trick:

```
/doi: ((\S+)(?:\. .+)?)\.$/
```

The outermost group (which captures the longer string) is capture group 1, and the innermost group is capture group 2.